# Is there an SE site that might support questions about micronationalism?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I have a few questions about micronations, and I am currently running one of my own. However, I can't find an SE site that would support such questions. It may be because I am just looking at the names of the sites and thinking "There's no way micronations would be supported there.", or it may just be my picky/judgey nature that's telling me that Law SE wouldn't support them either, since I'm guessing they've got better questions to answer then one about how to run a tiny country whose national bird is the scarlet macaw, but the birds aren't even native to the area.

Sorry if I got off-topic there. But I just can't seem to find a site that would support such a thing. Believe me, I'd go to quora, but people on that site aren't exactly happy when they see my account on the site is still active. By that, I mean like on most Q and A websites, I am disliked.

By the way, if there is not, I have proposed a site dedicated to micronations before, but it was shot down in a matter of days. So don't say I didn't try.

**TL;DR:** Is there an SE website that allows questions about micronations?

Answer (score 3):

I see one well-received question about micronations on [Politics](https://politics.stackexchange.com/):

[At what point can a micronation establish its own laws?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/23490/at-what-point-can-a-micronation-establish-its-own-laws)

I also saw a couple answers discussing micronations using a [search](https://politics.stackexchange.com/search?q=micronation).

Comment: Ok thank you. I'll go check it out. I think the problem was I was looking in law and not politics. Come to think of it, Politics makes more sense for a micronational question anyway.

Comment: @Xenon: How did it go?